# <rich:select> does not show all items in search mode

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using rich:select component in my xhtml page

My requirements are :

1) rich:select should be searchable.
2) But should show all elements in the list when clicking the down arrow, irrespective of the search string present.

For making  component searchable, I set enableManualInput=true. But,when I search and select some value, and later click on the down arrow (the dropdown expand) it does not show all items in the Dropdown list, but shows only the item currently selected. What happens is, the value of the currently selected item is set as the search prefix.

I need to manually remove all characters on the search field and start searching again.

Is there a workaround for this? Where I want a dropdown of list and also should be able to search through the list. If this component does not support this functionality, is there another alternative component?

I use richfaces 4 and JSF 2.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the value deleted each time the list is shown (i.e. when you click the input field or the button):

```
<rich:select id="select" value="#{bean.selectValue}" enableManualInput="true" 
    onlistshow="#{rich:component('select')}.setValue('')">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in RichFaces:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11088

It is planned to be fixed in 4.5.0, meanwhile you can take a fix from the pull request:
https://github.com/richfaces4/components/commit/79657a54c90e99bfa1fb5f42eab8bf6f29fc9091